# Laravel: relation between models

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i'm trying to get through a model to achive another model's data. 
The app has a few models:

Products: has many Portions (Small, Medium)
Portions: has many PortionIngredients (ingredient_id - 100g OR 10pcs)
PortionIngredients: has many Ingredients (Bacon, Cheese)
Ingredients: has many Translations (in 3 languages)

Product table

```
id
category_id
product_name
```

Portions table

```
id
product_id
portion_name
portion_weight
```

PortionIngredients

```
id
portion_id
ingredient_id
amount
```

Ingredients

```
id
base_unit
transaction_unit
multiplier
```

I've already tried to make relations in models with hasMany and belongsTo but without success. I'm trying to get all the ingredients for a portion of product. Any idea is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not a laravel expert, just a advise, did you try with has-many-through? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through

Comment: @Xiabili : Thanks for your advice, but hasManyThrough can make relation between 3 models. The problem is that i need to get 4 model's data. (in some cases i need to get through 5-6 models)

Comment: From the laravel docs, I can not find any function which allows you to get through 5 or 6 models, as so far, I think you should use the Query Builder to build a join query between those tables... like this: Ingredients::join('portion_ingredients as pi', 'pi.ingredient_id', '=', 'ingredients.id')->join('portions', 'portions.id', '=', 'pi.portions_id')->where('portions.product_id', 2)->get(); (not sure if working, not test yet)

Comment: You'll need to build a query as @Xiabili said above. There is no way to direct access a relation through this amount of models using Laravel's ORM. Actually, I don't know if any ORM will let you do something like that. Anyway, using the Query Builder you'll probably have a better query than accessing the objects through relation methods. Refer to the following link for more info: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Answer (score 0):

If relationship between models are set properly, similar to this:

```
// models/Product.php
class Product extends Model
{
    public portions() {
        return $this->hasMany("Portion");
    }
}

// models/Portion.php
class Portion extends Model
{
    public product() {
        return $this->belongsTo("Product");
    }
    public ingredients() {
        return $this->belongsToMany("Ingredient");
    }
}

// models/Ingredient.php
class Ingredient extends Model
{
    public portions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany("Portion");
    }
}
```

It should be possible to fetch a product with all of its portions and portions ingredients like this :

`$product = Product::with("portions.ingredients")->find($id)`

Check [Nested Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) in Laravel docs